# Disable blinking cursor in monaco web editor

Tags: monaco-editor

Using https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/breadth-first-search/practice-problems/algorithm/containers-of-choclates-1/

It uses Monaco web editor, I need help setting the right CSS to disable the blinking cursor. I couldnt find the cursor element in DOM

I am using STyleBot chrome extension to provide custom CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out myself Need custom CSS

```
.monaco-editor .cursors-layer .cursor {
visibility: inherit;
}
```

This seems to work for any monaco web editor

Comment: Thanks so much! I was struggling with this for a long time and couldn't get my custom CSS to stop the cursor from blinking. This helped me out a lot.

Comment: I needed the `!important` tag to work in my case.